# What is the difference between listStore and arrayList?

Tags: java

I have application which the front end written by qxt and I realize that there is two types of create the list :

```
obj1 = new ListStore<X>(); 
obj2 = new ArrayList<Y>();
```

what is the different between `obj1` and `obj2`?

Comment: Can you please put more efforts next time you ask a question?

Comment: Have you looked over the documentation for each?

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList is the default Java implementation otherwise ListStore is the GWT (Google Web Toolkit) implementation.

Here you can read about their utilizations and differences.

- [ListStore](https://docs.sencha.com/gxt-guides/3/data/store/ListStore.html)
- [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)